# Organizing files in lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to extract a portion of my Rails project into my lib directory but I can't work out how to link my files up correctly. My directory structure looks like this:

```
lib/
  eventable/
    calendar.rb
    helpers.rb
# Rest of rails directories/files
```

I'm requiring the eventable directory in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/lib/eventable)
```

My helpers and calendar rb files:

```
# helpers.rb
module Eventable
  module Helpers
    def calendar_for...
      Calendar.new...
    end
  end
end

# calendar.rb
module Eventable
  class Calendar
    # methods defined here
  end
end
```

I'm then mixing my Eventable::Helpers module in the regular Rails helpers so that I can use `calendar_for` in my views:

```
ActionView::Base.send :include, Eventable::Helpers
```

This last step seems to work fine. However, when I go to a view which is using this helper I get:

```
uninitialized constant Eventable::Helpers::Calendar
```

If I change my helper so that it tries to access `Eventable::Calendar.new` instead then I get:

```
uninitialized constant Eventable::Calendar
```

When I had all of these in a single file, it all worked perfectly. So how I can correctly link these files up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by changing the way modules are required.

In **application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/"]
```

Create **/lib/eventable.rb** with the following code

```
require "eventable/helpers"
require "eventable/calendar"
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Do you know why this is necessary? Is it because the autoloading fails to load them in the correct order? Or because the fact that I am using the Calendar class from a view helper is not enough to tell Rails that the class needs to be autoloaded (i.e. by the time it gets there, it is too late?)

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the order or helpers. The problem comes from Ruby. Modules location should match the directory structure, as you did, but when they are required directly from the subdirectory it raises an error. Take a look at this: [Best practice for Ruby require](http://devblog.vworkapp.com/post/910714976/best-practice-for-rubys-require).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need a loader-type file to tell Rails where to find code for the `Eventable` module.

Try add a `lib/eventable.rb` with:

```
module Eventable
  autoload :Calendar, 'eventable/calendar'
  autoload :Helpers, 'eventable/helpers'
end
```

You shouldn't need to change your load path if you have the loader file in place.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried creating that file but I get the following error: `cannot load such file -- eventable/calendar`. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?  A couple of things to try are to add the '.rb' to the autoloads or and to take the lib/eventable path out of your load path.  By just having the lib directory in your load path it should pick up the eventable.rb loader.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.3p125 and have tried removing the eventable dir from my load path (i.e. just lib directory in there now) and tried with '.rb' but all give me the same error. Wawa's answer worked for me though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also thanks for introducing me to the concept of a loader-type file

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the official term for it - but that's the idea of it.  The same concept is used when gems get loaded, see https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form.rb